# Why android explorer gives only empty folder when backing up?

Tags: droid-explorer

I am backing up my xiaomi redmi note 3

These is the screenshot

[image]

Then I create backup

[image]

It may be related to

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138954/cannot-take-adb-backup

Comment: That is strange. As the developer of droid explorer, I will have to re-test this as this looks like it may be a bug. But, I do not want to close this (as bugs should not be reported here), until I can confirm that it actually is a bug. That folder should not be a folder. The name is what the file should be called.

Comment: I suspected that the problem is in adb backup itself. If I do this the hard way (via command line), I got a message saying that I will be prompted to enter my password. I am never prompted.  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138954/cannot-take-adb-backup

Comment: hmm, interesting. if you are never prompted, that could be why the folder is created and empty. it is technically waiting for your input, but it isn't prompting you. The prompt is on your phone btw.